# Atlas in Differential Geometry: one of the transitions functions is wrong

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, fiber-bundles

In the book *Connections in classical and quantum field theory*  by *L. Mangiarotti, G. Sardanashvily*
I have a problem with $(1.1.3)$ formula below:
$$(x,v)\mapsto (x,\rho_{\xi\zeta}(x,v));$$

namely that  $$\rho_{\xi\zeta}(x,v)$$ should lie in $V$ but as is, it lies in $$(U_\xi\cap U_\zeta)\times V$$

[image]

**What is the correct formula for the 2nd line in $(1.1.3)$ ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\rho$ acts trivially on the $x$-coordinate, it seems like an abuse of notation that the second coordinate of $\rho$ is $\rho$ itself. You could make up your own notation for the second coordinate such as $\rho(x,v) = (x, \sigma(x,v))$.

In the case of the tangent bundle, if $x^i$ and $y^j$ are coordinates that are overlapping at some point $x$, then the map $\rho$ near $x$ in coordinates would be $\rho(x,v) = (x, M(x)v)$, where $M(x)$ is the linear map sending $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}|_x$ to $\frac{\partial y^j}{\partial x^i}(x)\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}|_x$, and $\sigma(x,v) = M(x)v$. Here $M(x) = \frac{\partial y^j}{\partial x^i}(x)$ is the Jacobian change of basis matrix computed at $x$.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. But what is $\sigma$ here then ?

Comment: @user122424: In the case of the tangent bundle, at least, $\sigma(x,v)$ would be of the form $\sigma_x(v)$, where $\sigma_x$ is a matrix sending $v$ to another vector $v'$. The map $\sigma$ itself would be regarded as a map from the base to what is essentially $GL_n$ in the case of the tangent bundle.

Comment: Could you kindly supply some concrete elaborated example in your answer ?

Comment: @user122424: I added some more details for the case of the tangent bundle